# How to update createdBy(author) field using powerhsell Sharepoint CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom

I need to update the CreatedBy(Author) field using CSOM Powershell Sharepoint Online.

I tried:

```
$user=$ctx.Web.EnsureUser("xxx@aa.onmicrosoft.com")

$ctx.Load($user)

$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

$listItem["Author"]=$user

$listItem.Update()

$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

But this is not updating .I have given mailid to EnsureUser() method because I have only mailId of the user.

can anyone help me with correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below PowerShell Script to can Update Created By / Modified By Fields values using PowerShell CSOM in SharePoint Online

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

##Variables for Processing
$SiteUrl = "https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/sales/"
$ListName= "Projects"
$ID=6
$UserID="Salaudeen@crescent.com"
$TimeStamp = "2015/12/01 02:10:00 AM"

#Get Credentials to connect
$Cred = Get-Credential
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)

#Setup the context
$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
$Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials

#Get the User
$User = $Ctx.Web.EnsureUser($UserID)
$ctx.Load($user)

#Get the list Item
$List=$Ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)
$ListItem = $List.GetItemById($ID)
$Ctx.Load($ListItem)

#Update Created by & Modified By
$ListItem["Author"] = $User
$ListItem['Editor'] = $User

#Set Created on & Modified on Time values
$ListItem["Created"] =  $TimeStamp
$ListItem["Modified"] = $TimeStamp

#Update List item
$ListItem.Update()
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

Write-host "Metadata values updated Successfully!" -f Green
```

**Credit to**: [SharePoint Online: Update Created By / Modified By, Created At / Modified At Field values using PowerShell CSOM](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/11/update-created-by-modified-by-created-at-modified-at-values-using-powershell.html#ixzz5NUvJEiEj)

Comment: This is working fine for custom list,but I am updating for a Page in Page library.I dont know why it is not getting updated for a page.But showing modified few seconds ago.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me (on SP2016 OnPrem) only when I change two fields at the same time

```
$listItem["Author"]=$user
$listItem["Editor"]=$user
```

just try it out, maybe it works also for you

Comment: this is working for me for custom lists  not for Page lib and Document library.I am working for SPOnline site.

Comment: This is working for me for both of types. It seems like SPO is (once again) slightly different than OnPrem...